# Setting Panning in OpenAL (iOS)

Tags: ios, openal

Using OpenAL, I am loading the sound in AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 format. I am trying to set the panning in OpenAL in iOS/iPhone platform? Do I need to set the AL_POSITION for the source? How do I set it?

Comment: I am loading the sound in AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 format. If I load it in MONO format, i am able to set the pan using

`float sourcePosAL[] = {pan, 0.0f, 0.0f};
alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_POSITION, sourcePosAL);`

pan value ranging from -1.0f to 1.0f.

Comment: How do I set the pan for a stereo file?

Comment: OpenAL says about AL_CHANNELS: "number of channels in buffer
> 1 is valid, but buffer won’t be positioned when played". So it's not possible with a 2-channel file. However, you could split the stereo file into 2 mono buffers and devise your own stereo-panning technique (ie. using AL_POSITION and/or AL_GAIN for each channel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I load it in MONO format, i am able to set the pan using

```
float sourcePosAL[] = {pan, 0.0f, 0.0f}; 
alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_POSITION, sourcePosAL);
```

pan value ranging from -1.0f to 1.0f.